# How to keep JavaFX MenuBar in the top part of the window

Tags: java, javafx, alignment, menubar

I'm trying to make an window, where I have StackPane as root and I want to add MenuBar to this window. However MenuBar is in the center of the screen and I want to keep it in the top part of the window as in normal Windows applications.

```
root = new StackPane();
root.getChildren().add(new MenuBar());
```

this will show window like this
http://i61.tinypic.com/2pzblmo.jpg

Thanks you for your advice!

Comment: Would it be more sane to use a `BorderPane` and add the menu bar in the TOP section? Then you can add the `StackPane` to the CENTER section of the `BorderPane`, or add the entire `BorderPane` in the `StackPane` depending on what you want to accomplish.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would say StackPane is not suitable for making a GUI including a menubar.
StackPane will just put the controls you add to it one on top of the other.
In java docs you can find:
"StackPane

The StackPane layout pane places all of the nodes within a single stack with each new node added on top of the previous node. This layout model provides an easy way to overlay text on a shape or image or to overlap common shapes to create a complex shape. Figure 1-6 shows a help icon that is created by stacking a question mark on top of a rectangle with a gradient background.
"